# Process.Start(), loop same exe and arguments, but just one process

Tags: vb.net, loops, process

I want start a process with some arguments X times.

The code is:

Some LOOP

```
Dim FirefoxP = New Process()
FirefoxP.StartInfo.FileName = "Pathfirefox\firefox.exe"
FirefoxP.StartInfo.Arguments = "something"
FirefoxP.Start()
```

... When the program finish (i can know it)

```
FirefoxP.Kill()
```

But I think that it is a ugly solution, I want the way for Call to exe that is running and give arguments again, without Kill the process.

Maybe there is a way for Call to a process that is running and send arguments :S

Regards.

Comment: You cannot. When you start the process you are basically calling a function with certain arguments. You cannot access a function you called and change the arguments while it is running. You can wait until whatever the function is doing ends and call the function again. Or... make a second (, third, etc.) parallel call to the same function; but not affect the original execution.

Comment: That is completely dependent upon how the **external EXE** handles being run.  Some applications are "single instances" and would process the new arguments in the same existing process.  Others may use the same process but add a new Tab or something, while others will open a new instance to handle the arguments.  Some may even allow you to specify how to handle this thru options or even command-line arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Then I will do it, but i will change Kill() per CloseMainWindow().
varocarbas when you say me that I can make a second parallel call, you refer with a new firefox.exe process, really?
Idle_Mind maybe firefox has the option for add new tab in the same process, I will see.
Thanks!!